# Ejected - IOS - Unrecognized Font Family (@expo-google-fonts/monserrat)

Tags: ios, fonts, expo

I have a recently ejected expo application (SDK 45)
I managed to get a build for IOS and launch it on my device.
As soon as the application starts, I get an error :
[Unrecognised font family error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PutvF.jpg)

I'm using @expo-google-fonts/monserrat.
That's how I load my fonts :

```
//Other Depedencies are here
import {
    Montserrat_100Thin,
    Montserrat_200ExtraLight,
    Montserrat_300Light,
    Montserrat_400Regular,
    Montserrat_400Regular_Italic,
    Montserrat_500Medium,
    Montserrat_600SemiBold,
    Montserrat_700Bold,
    Montserrat_800ExtraBold,
    useFonts
} from '@expo-google-fonts/montserrat';

const App = (): JSX.Element => {
    const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        Montserrat_100Thin,
        Montserrat_200ExtraLight,
        Montserrat_300Light,
        Montserrat_400Regular_Italic,
        Montserrat_400Regular,
        Montserrat_500Medium,
        Montserrat_600SemiBold,
        Montserrat_700Bold,
        Montserrat_800ExtraBold
    });

    React.useEffect(() => {
        async function prepare(): Promise<void> {
            try {
                await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
            } catch (e) {
                console.warn(e);
            }
        }

        void prepare();
    }, []);

    const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
        if (fontsLoaded) {
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }
    }, [fontsLoaded]);

    return (
        <ContentOfTheApp/>
     );
 };
```

I tried some solution i saw on several post, here are my ios project configuration concerning the fonts :

[Fonts added in my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnHFl.png)

[Fonts declared in the info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZiPl.png)

[Fonts files listed in Copy Bundle Ressources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOTWq.png)

I tried to reinstall pods, clearing build folder, updating @expo-google-font and expo-font...

I don't know what i'm missing here and a little bit of help would be appreciated :)

EDIT : Typo in the title

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `useFonts()`, replacing with `Font.loadAsync()` solves the problem:

```
//inside your prepare hook
await Font.loadAsync({
  Montserrat_100Thin,
  Montserrat_200ExtraLight,
  Montserrat_300Light,
  Montserrat_400Regular_Italic,
  Montserrat_400Regular,
  Montserrat_500Medium,
  Montserrat_600SemiBold,
  Montserrat_700Bold,
  Montserrat_800ExtraBold
});
```